# for loop parsing of ls and the magic behind *

Tags: bash, ls, for

I know that the following is bad:

> ```
> for i in `ls -1 *.MOV` ;do ...
> ```

and that the proper syntax is

> ```
> for i in  *.MOV ;do ...
> ```

But what are the mechanics behind it?  I mean, what part of `*.MOV` tells the for command that I'm talking about filenames?  Is there an assumption made in the `for` code that says "given no other parameters, assume filenames"?

And... if `ls` output is bad inside of for, what is for doing to get a usable list of filenames that it wont choke on?

Comment: "I know that the following is bad" – Good. For users who don't know: [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @FelixJN That was an excellent article, thank you, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes :-) The shell is expanding the wildcard to the set of files matching the wild-card expression, in your example the MOV files in the current directory. But six other kinds of expansion must be considered before this happens.

'Expansion' is described in a detailed way in the manual `man bash`.

> **EXPANSION**
>
> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split
> into words.  There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace
> expansion,  tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command
> substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname
> expansion.
>
> ...
>
> **Pathname Expansion**
>
> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of  these
> characters  appears, then  the  word  is  regarded  as  a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see
> Pattern Matching below).  If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged.

Comment: This is very helpful for the first part of my question.  Excellent, thank you!  Now for the second part -- how is "for" or the "shell expansion" putting the list of filenames in $i in a way that doesn't break everything following that would depend on $i ? Is it that there is no interpretation of the filename content with the pathname expansion, but that ls tries to interpret special characters in some way that botches it?  I'm just trying to understand the underlying mechanism where in one case $i can be trusted to be accurate and in the other way it can't.

Comment: The glob `*.MOV` is replaced by the set of matching files. Thereafter the loop can be considered to iterate across a set of literals: `for f in first.MOV second.MOV third.MOV`

Comment: @mikem: `ls` itself doesn't do anything bad, but (per the man page) _command substitution_ with backticks or `$( ... )` is normally followed by word splitting and (another) pathname expansion, which can damage your values. These _can_ be suppressed by `set -f` and changing `IFS` (unless your filenames ever contain newline because that becomes ambiguous, plus any _trailing_ newlines are removed), but doing that tends to break other things. And `for i in *x` _sets_ `i` correctly but remember you still must doublequote its _expansion_ `"$i"` or _that_ may mangle.